# Informix SQL Error (-271): Could not insert new row into the table

Tags: informix

I tried to create a 30 GB dbspace using Informix Administration API with the following command:

```
EXECUTE FUNCTION task ("create dbspace", "DBS01", "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\OL_INF~1\dbspaces\DBS01.01", "15 G", "0");
```

It creates the file with 30 GB but finally not adding it to the list of DB spaces and throws the following error:

```
SQL Error (-271): Could not insert new row into the table.
ISAM error: Lock Timeout Expired
```

Even if I try to create the DB space for 15 GB, it throws the same error after creating the file of 15 GB.

How can avoid this problem?

Comment: The table it is inserting into (or, rather, failing to insert into) is almost certainly not related to the dbspace file, but is in one of the system catalogs in the root dbspace, or thereabouts.  The tables are probably in the `sysmaster` database, or one of the other `sys*` databases.  Take a good look at the online log file; the chances are that there is information in there that will help identify where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Total shared memory is 1 GB (1048576 KB).  Is this the problem?

Comment: Very unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Nothing much is there in the online log except the information about the shared memory.  I could create dbspace for 7 GB but when I try to create it with 8 GB, it fails.  Any idea, why this limitation is?

Comment: One more issue is, I am trying to import the exported files from another DB server.  DB export file size is about 780 MB.  I could successfully import in a Linux server.  When I tried to import the same in my local windows machines, it throws the following error:   25582 - Network connection is broken.  54 - Connection reset by peer.  After this, local informix install crashes and could not start the Informix service.  Please help.

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, nor an Informix on Windows expert.  Are you using a 32-bit version of Windows, or a 32-bit version of Informix?  Does the version number end `.TCx` or `.FCx` for some digit `x` (e.g. `.TC1`)?  Come to that, what's the full version number?  If 7 GiB works and 8 GiB fails, it begins to sound like you're trying to create a file that's too big for either the o/s or the version of Informix.  If the exported data is around 800 MiB, then you should be able to fit that into a similar size dbspace.  It may occupy a bit more space because of indexes.

Comment: Error -25582 probably means the server crashed while the import occurred.  Have you tried using `onspaces` to create the dbspace instead of the function?  It's old fashioned, but it's also different.  You should probably consider contacting IBM/Informix Tech Support.